# In the Injekt library for Kotlin, how do I inject functions instead of just values?

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, kohesive-injekt

**When using Injekt library in Kotlin for dependency injection:**

Instead of injecting a value, sometimes I want to inject a function.  So something like receiving the function by:

```kotlin
 val function: (Int) -> Int = Injekt.get()
```

This seems to work ok, but not if I register more than one function with the same signature but different meaning.  There doesn't appear to be a way to differentiate the functions.

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Injekt + Kotlin topics are present in SO.  Other answers are also welcome, there are other styles of how to do this!  Disclosure, I am the author of the Injekt library.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the functions boil down to an internal representation of the signature, for example in this case as:

```
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer, ? extends java.lang.Integer>
```

And any function that has the same parameter and return type will have the same internal type and appear to be the same to Injekt.  The following registrations are all valid and do not conflict:

```
// register some functions

Injekt.addSingletonFactory {
    val function: (value: Int) -> Int = { value -> value + 1 }
    function
}

Injekt.addSingletonFactory {
    val function: (Long) -> Long = { value -> value - 1 }
    function
}

Injekt.addSingletonFactory {
    val function: (Long) -> String = { value -> "The long is $value" }
    function
}

// inject and use the functions

val intFunction: (Int) -> Int = Injekt.get()
val intResult = intFunction(2)

val longFunction: (Long) -> Long = Injekt.get()
val longResult = longFunction(2)

val longStringFunction: (Long) -> String = Injekt.get()
val stringResult = longStringFunction(10)
```

If you want to use the same function signature as different meaning, you can create a class wrapper for each meaning of the function:

```
class Int1Action(val function: (Int) -> Int) {
    operator fun invoke(i: Int): Int = function(i)
}
```

By adding the `invoke` operator, you can naturally use this wrapper without referencing the `function` member, such as:

```
Injekt.addSingletonFactory {
    val function: (Int) -> Int = { value -> value + 20 }
    Int1Action(function)
}

val action: Int1Action = Injekt.get()
val result = action(2) // call it directly using the invoke operator
```